# Querying SnowFlake with parameters from MacOs Excel (ODBC)?

Tags: excel, macos, odbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to test reports creation in Excel (MacOS version) to SnowFlake Datasource.

Simple querying to SnowFlake using ODBC works fine (except [initial setup difficulties](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Configuring-Excel-on-a-Mac-to-use-Snowflake)).

But when I tried to pass some parameters into the query:

- parameters including via ODBC does not work
  [image: Question mark parameter is not supported?]
  [image: Parameters button disabled]
- Other way to do query with parameters could be [via PowerQuery connection](https://www.excelforum.com/access-tables-and-databases/1301221-using-parameters-in-querying-data-from-snowflake-with-odbc.html). But as I see on the [official MS website](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-power-query-in-excel-for-mac-7b2f337d-e7d2-4fdf-bf00-3dfbb1e5e9c5):

> **Use VBA to author Power Query queries Although authoring in the Power**
>
> Query Editor is not yet available in Excel for Mac, VBA does support
> Power Query authoring. Here is some basic code you can adapt and use.

So, is it really so, that the only way to build report with parameters by querying SnowFlake from MacOS Excel - is try to [use some VBA scripting](https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00008tOe5xSAC/is-it-possible-to-use-excel-vba-macro-to-readupdate-data-from-snowflake)?

Or I just did not find how to use parameters passing via ODBC connection?

Many thanks in advance for your advice!

Comment: If you can use Windows or Parallels, open-source Excelerator can meet a lot of this use-case.  https://github.com/Snowflake-Labs/Excelerator.  Cloud native Sigma Computing also makes a great tool to also query Snowflake to meet this use case as an alternative to coding this in Mac Excel.

Comment: Windows and Parallels are not the options, the end users are using MacOS.
3rd party reporting tools planned to be tested also, thank you for mentioning of Sigma Computing

Comment: @Allen I am trying to test Sigma Computing now. But I can't find there how to fill parameter values list dynamically using a query to database. Is there is a way to do it?

Comment: Please reach out to Sigma: https://www.sigmacomputing.com/contact-us/